# how to find three tables data using sequelize?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

**Tables:**

[image]

**Table associations:**

```
 //category_product with category
category.hasMany(category_product,{foreignKey:'category_id'})
category_product.belongsTo(category,{foreignKey:'category_id'})

//category_product with Product
Product.hasMany(category_product,{foreignKey:'product_id'})
category_product.belongsTo(Product, {foreignKey: 'product_id'})
```

**Git bash error**

```
throw new Error(this.name + '.hasMany called with something that\'s not asubclass of Sequelize.Model');
  ^

Error: Theme.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model
```

Thanks!

Comment: This link may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/44076602/2893413

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

This is my way [mini-shop](https://github.com/Tzcodejs/mini-shop/tree/master/server)