# Sequelize.Model relationship not working in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Hello I am new user to NodeJs and I integrated Sequelize library in my NodeJs project and defined my models. When I add relashionship with model then it gives me following error

> > throw new Error(`${source.name}.${_.lowerFirst(Type.name)} called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model`);
> >           ^
>
> Error: user_posts_boxes.belongsTo called with something that's not a
>   subclass of Sequelize.Model
>       at Function. (/home/rizwan/php/nodejs/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/mixin.js:93:13)
>   My Post Model

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function (sequelize) {
    var Post = sequelize.define('user_posts', {

    }, {timestamp: false});

    return Post;
};
```

My PostBox model

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var Post = require('./Post');

module.exports = function (sequelize) {
    var PostBox = sequelize.define('user_posts_boxes', {
    }, {timestamp: false});

    PostBox.belongsTo(Post, {foreignKey: 'user_pots_id'});
    return PostBox;
};
```

During research I found help from following link
[hasMany called with something that's not an instance of Sequelize.Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070808/hasmany-called-with-something-thats-not-an-instance-of-sequelize-model)

Suggest me any use full waay and reference link

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined any columns in your `PostBox` model. 
Try with:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var Post = require('./Post');

module.exports = function (sequelize) {
    var PostBox = sequelize.define('user_posts_boxes', 
    {
      post_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: Post,
            key: "post_id" // this is the `posts.post_id` column - name it according to your posts table definition (the one defined in ./Post)
        }
      }
    }, {timestamp: false});

    PostBox.belongsTo(Post, {foreignKey: 'post_id'});
    return PostBox;
};
```

Comment: still same problem

Comment: please post the `./Post` model in your question body, because that might not actually be a Sequelize component